# Cartoon about a team of three people augmented by mechanical parts

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I don't know much about this cartoon but I want to find the name of it.

The cartoon used to broadcasted in late 90s till mid 2000s. Cartoon consisted of three members. When some problem arose, all three members had mechanical parts joined to their whole body. And of the three members, one had air parts attached, one had land parts attached, and the last one used to go under water.

Comment: Is there any more information you can add?  For instance, what type of problems did they deal with?  Were they fighting villains or helping with natural disasters?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179746/sci-fi-cartoon-show-with-an-elite-soldiers-group (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 14):

Could this be "[The Centurions](http://www.80scartoons.net/toons/centurions.html)"? They had a three man team, complete with cybernetic enhancements that allowed them to fly, go underwater, etc.

The timescale is a bit early (1980s) but apart from that a pretty good match.

Answer (score 9):

Aside from the timeframe you believe it was, this sounds to be [The Centurions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Centurions_%28TV_series%29), which first aired in the 1980's.

The show started with three members of the Centurions - each with a different specialty: air, earth, and water. When called to action, they would attach parts and weapons to their suits, enabling them to fly, swim, etc.

[image: check out all three dudes in their fancy armor]

[image: of course there were toys of them.]

Comment: I loved this show back in the day! The team in Inhumanoids was of a similar vein.