# Sci-fi cartoon show with an elite soldiers group

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

There was this sci-fi animated series. A cartoon show, if you must. It had a group of men and a woman who were part of some special elite group. The had lego blocks sort-of-a-thing on their body (not sure if as a part of their armour). Whenever the need arose, special weapons or types of equipment would attach to their backs, their arms etc.
For example, you could attach jetpack wings to the back and basically fly. Or you could attach a gun to your arm.

I am just able to remember one particular scene and have mentioned all that I could recall from it.

All the characteristics of the show I would now further describe may be from a completely different series and just mixed up with this memory.

There was this white dude, who was the leader of this squad and would get the best possible equipments for a particular fighting climax.

The setting was a pretty modern day era, which I don't think had dark gloomy alien species. Completely not sure about this part though.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Some elements of your description match with [*The Centurions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Centurions_(TV_series)), an animations series + associated toy line dating back to the 80s:

> It had a group of men and a woman who were part of some special elite group.

The main protagonists are three men (later episodes add two more guys) forming the eponymous special sqad, but there is an important female character providing technical support.

[image]

<sub>(image from [Power Extreme Wiki](http://powerextreme.wikia.com/wiki/The_Centurions))</sub>

> The had lego blocks sort-of-a-thing on their body (not sure if as a part of their armour). Whenever the need arose, special weapons or types of equipment would attach to their backs, their arms etc

[image]

Comment: don't forget the toys! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JxCIofw-aI

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much. Seeing the second picture, getting back memories of how the weapons used to attach in a time-warp like sequence.

Comment: They were also pretty clearly set up to represent three major military forces- Army, Navy and Marines, Air Force. Even as a little kid I remember thinking it felt like propaganda. I may just be reading into it too much tho.

Answer (score 6):

**Exo Squad**

This was my first thought. I grew up in the 90s and remember watching this show religiously. [Exo Squad Opening Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exosquad)

[image: Exo Squad Suits]

Not sure about your "lego" description, although the toys did include interchangeable weapons.

Comment: It's so interesting how this fits the premise too. Thank you so much, but The Centurions was what I was trying to identify.